# User Choose File for Data Connector in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-selected-items

I am here to ask if it is possible for the user to select a file to be used for the Data Connector in Power Apps. I am making a Power App to help with payroll in my company and I need the person who is using it to be able to pick the file. There is a different excel sheet for each week. Because of this, I cannot just connect one spreadsheet to the app. Each spreadsheet every week is formatted the exact same way, so the app will be able to perform the required calculations once a week when it is used. I just need help figuring out how to let the user pick the file for the Data Connector, if there is in fact a way to do this.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but you probably should add all excel files to Data Connector.

Then add a field for the user to select the week and based on its selection choose the data source.